# android - ListView Item not showing in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have Navigation Drawer with Fragment. 
I set custom ListView  from URL In Fragment. 
But when I am running this, Items in ListView are not showing .
Data shows in log cat as well. i donot get any error on logcat

**Fragment:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    JSONArray post = null;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> PostList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private View rootView;
    private ListView list;
    private StringRequest sr;
    private RequestQueue queue;
    private JSONArray laporanListObj;
    private int Jumlah_list_Data;
    private Adapter_Post adapter;
    private Animation animstatuskoneksi;
    private TextView statusKoneksi;
    private ImageView nodata;
    private ProgressBar load;
    private Handler handler;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        // adapter list
        adapter = new Adapter_Post(getActivity(), PostList);
        // animasi
        animstatuskoneksi = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                R.anim.anim_status_koneksi);
        // View Declare
        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        statusKoneksi = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.status_koneksi);
        nodata = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.NoData);
        load = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.load);
        // set adapter
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Listview on item click listener
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                TextView judul = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.judul);
                TextView waktu_post = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.waktu_post);
                TextView id_post = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_post);
                TextView link_detail_post = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.link_detail_post);

                String var_judul = judul.getText().toString();
                String var_waktu_post = waktu_post.getText().toString();
                String var_id_post = id_post.getText().toString();
                String var_link_detail_post = link_detail_post.getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                // Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                // in.putExtra(Variabel.KEY_JUDUL, var_judul);
                // in.putExtra(Variabel.KEY_WAKTU_POST, var_waktu_post);
                // in.putExtra(Variabel.KEY_ID_POST, var_id_post);
                // in.putExtra(Variabel.KEY_LINK_DETAIL_POST,
                // var_link_detail_post);
                // startActivity(in);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "oke", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        GetDataPost(Variabel.url_post);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void GetDataPost(String url) {

        if (queue != null) {
            queue.cancelAll(sr);
        }

        // adapter.delete_all();
        load.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Log.v("Get Data", url);
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.v("hasil", response);
                        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        DrawData(response);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            statusKoneksi("Koneksi bermasalah");
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            statusKoneksi("Server Error");
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            statusKoneksi("Koneksi Timeout");
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            statusKoneksi("Ada masalah dalam mengambil data");
                        } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            statusKoneksi("Tidak ada koneksi");
                        } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            statusKoneksi("Koneksi Timeout");
                        }

                        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonParams.put("tag", Variabel.tag_default);
                return jsonParams;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);

    }

    protected void DrawData(String response) {

        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            json = new JSONObject(response);
            String res = json.getString(Variabel.KEY_SUCCESS);
            String msg_err = json.getString(Variabel.KEY_ERROR_MSG);

            if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {

                laporanListObj = json.getJSONArray(Variabel.KEY_POST);
                Jumlah_list_Data = laporanListObj.length();

                if (Jumlah_list_Data > 0) {

                    // count_data.setText(Jumlah_list_Data+" Data");
                    list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    nodata.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    for (int i = 0; i < Jumlah_list_Data; i++) {

                        JSONObject c = laporanListObj.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        Variabel.judul_post = c.getString(Variabel.KEY_JUDUL);
                        Variabel.waktu_post = c
                                .getString(Variabel.KEY_WAKTU_POST);
                        Variabel.id_post = c.getString(Variabel.KEY_ID_POST);
                        Variabel.link_detail_post = c
                                .getString(Variabel.KEY_LINK_DETAIL_POST);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(Variabel.KEY_JUDUL, Variabel.judul_post);
                        map.put(Variabel.KEY_WAKTU_POST, Variabel.waktu_post);
                        map.put(Variabel.KEY_ID_POST, Variabel.id_post);
                        map.put(Variabel.KEY_LINK_DETAIL_POST,
                                Variabel.link_detail_post);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        PostList.add(map);
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            } else {

                list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                statusKoneksi(msg_err);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Listview Adapter:**

```
public class Adapter_Post extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private ImageLoaderDetailImage ImageLoader;
    private int loader;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public Adapter_Post(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ImageLoader = new ImageLoaderDetailImage(activity.getBaseContext());
        loader = R.drawable.ic_drawer;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void delete_all() {
        int count = getCount();
        if (count > 0) {
            data.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {

        public TextView judul;
        public TextView waktu_post;
        public TextView id_post;
        public TextView link_detail_post;

        // public RoundedImageView foto_bus;

    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.from(activity)
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            // holder.foto_bus =
            // (RoundedImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.foto_bus);
            holder.judul = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.judul);
            holder.waktu_post = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.waktu_post);
            holder.id_post = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.id_post);
            holder.link_detail_post = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.link_detail_post);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> kendaraan = new HashMap<String, String>();
        kendaraan = data.get(position);
        // set data
        holder.judul.setText(kendaraan.get(Variabel.KEY_JUDUL));
        holder.waktu_post.setText(kendaraan.get(Variabel.KEY_WAKTU_POST));
        holder.id_post.setText(kendaraan.get(Variabel.KEY_ID_POST));
        holder.link_detail_post.setText(kendaraan
                .get(Variabel.KEY_LINK_DETAIL_POST));

        // ImageLoader.DisplayImage(kendaraan.get(Variabel.KEY_FOTO_BUS),loader,
        // holder.foto_bus);

        return vi;
    }

}
```

**UPDATED**

Fragment XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        </ListView>

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/load"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NoData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/nodata"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_koneksi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#99000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="msg."
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

any mistake in my code ? 
How to fix it ? 
sorry for my english .. thanks

Comment: check out the answer of @M D. Show logcat errors

Comment: Also see if you are setting the visibility of listview at right position

Comment: visibility of listview right. On my device the scroll of listView is showed, but without view item ..

Comment: try to set adapter after getting data from server.

Answer (score 1):

you should change this

```
list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

to

```
list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

and make sure you have `ListView` with **id** `list` in your `fragment_home` layout.

Comment: logcat is well sir, not get error. but On my device the scroll of listView is showed, but without view item ..

Comment: @user3216348 That means when your ListView is Bind it's not full Visible becoz may be some Layout or View Overlay and hide your ListView...

Answer (score 1):

In **getview** method of adapter change the parameters of this:

> vi = inflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

to:

```
vi = inflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```